# How to use a Thread to check every time (like running it in background) until my condition is true

Tags: java, multithreading

I have this code sample. But everytime I run it, **It won't wait until my condition is true**
I need this `Thread` to be like something that continuously looking until the condition is true.

My condition is: **sum.contains(jLabel11.getText())**

I need the `Thread` to work until this condition becomes true.
Using a `while(true)` statement do this thing, but sometime it will be a bad condition for the program because it will keep printing and printing thousands of lines (in my case: "*Not equal yet*") until the condition inside `if` statement is `true`

But I really need this `Thread` to look over and over (continuously) until my condition in `if` statement is `true` without printing the `statement` in `else condition` thousand times or without printing the `statement` in `if condition` thousand times even after my condition inside `if statement` is true. But I need to print the `statement` inside `if` statement **only one time** to know that my condition became `true`

```
new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                        if (sum.contains(jLabel11.getText())) {
                            System.out.println("Now equal");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Not equal yet");
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(AlarmClock.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }

                }

            }.start();
```

Comment: You need an infinite loop essentially, followed by a `break` upon the correct condition being found. You're running this once at the moment and regardless of the result the thread hits the end. Also, I wouldn't make an anonymous subclass of thread, but instead make a `Runnable` and pass it to the thread constructor.

Comment: Instead of `while(true)`, you can use your condition inside the while. Also, I hope there's another thread that's probably setting that condition to true at some point, otherwise it's just an infinite loop. You should break once that condition is true. And yes, use `Runnable`.

Comment: Sir, You mean implementing the `Runnable` @Swapnil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution seems simple, just add the while(true) and if it goes inside the condition breaks the execution to go out the while and out the thread, something like this:

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true){
                if (sum.contains(jLabel11.getText())) {
                    System.out.println("Now equal");
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AlarmClock.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}.start();
```

Now, as explained in other answers, this is called a selfish thread which tend to demand more resources than a monitor or other event-like patterns.

On new Architectures (SMP = Symmetric Multi processor) selfish threads are not an issue... but there are some architectures where it can be really a problem (such MPP Massive Parallel Processor architectures)

Now, regarding the statement you stated:

**It won't wait until my condition is true I**

It seems your main thread is reaching its end before this new Thread you are creating...

For example, if you have that code in an Unit Test (JUnit), you have to put a thread.sleep to wait until the condition is fulfill, or Mock sum.contains(jLabel11.getText()) to unit test it...

If not, the main thread will finish and all its child threads will be terminated with it.

Comment: can you add a sleep to this.  it looks dangerous with out it.

Comment: Sure it can be added, but the sleep depends on the requirement, and the volume of information they are going to process, if they need to process it realtime, they have to omit the sleep...  Anyway, on SMP infrastructures (Such any Unix like/windows like OS) where servers has multiple processors and each processor multiple cores, selfish threads can be handled with no issues by the kernel due the thread scheduling.

Answer (score 1):

While you could do as Rogue suggests, it's almost always a terrible idea.  It wastes a *lot* of computing power on having a thread "spin" (i.e. sit in a loop continuously testing a condition).  It also does not offer a particularly good guarantee of the thread noticing "right away" (or within any given time frame) when the condition becomes true.  (You would need a real-time threading system to provide that kind of guarantee.)

You'll get at least as good a responsiveness, and without unnecessarily occupying a processor, using monitors.  In java every object is potentially a monitor.  Check out the JavaDoc for `notify` and `wait` as a good starting point.

So a simple pattern that mght work: you create a monitor, your background thread waits on that monitor, and any operation that could affect the condition to be tested calls `notify` on the monitor.  Your thread, when awoken, checks the condition and either does its work or goes back to sleep (by again `wait`ing), accordingly.

Comment: Can you answer by giving an example sir?

Answer (score -1):

Then do it like this:

```
   while(!(sum.contains(jLabel11.getText())){
Thread.yield();
}
System.out.println("Now equal");
```

Comment: I didn´t downvoted and have no idea who did it, but I think it was because this answer is not related to the question itself: Thread.yield() just let the OS know to schedule any other thread that is waiting the processor (if there are any), but the question itself was asking something different. This being said, the code compiles... the code runs... but since this does not have a clear intention of answering the question, it normally gets downvoted.